Dragnet (1967 version) episode about a hippie leader with sunglasses
I don't know if many of you know or care much about the 60s version of Dragnet.
But I'm trying to find a particular episode where Joe Friday and his partner go into some hippie drug house. There's like a 'leader' there with a beard and sunglasses. He runs kind of a hotel for other hippie druggies. I think there is guns involved but forgot. Also a girl or two is missing and hangs out there. Maybe even a young dude. Anyway, the hippie leader with the sunglasses refuses to take them off because: (paraphrasing here) "I just don't like the world I see around me maaan. When I take my sunglasses off I just don't like what I see". Eventually Joe Friday and his partner get him in the end and such and close the hippie pad down at the end. I think there might've been an elevator in the episode for this 'hippie hotel' the bearded sunglasses hippie leader ran.
I watched the episode with a friend and we laughed our asses off. Now I can't find this episode for the life of me no matter what.

That is is the first episode of the 1967 season (and was available on Netflix not too long ago).  

Friday and Gannon encounter Benjy "Blue Boy" Carver, an LSD user.
  Because of the then-lack of any laws against the use of LSD, they are
  unable to make a case against him, and Carver's parents are of no
  help. Finally, legislation is passed against LSD use and sale, but by
  then it may be too late for "Blue Boy".

